# How to get a class type from formatted string like "%d %s %f"? in Java

Tags: java

I've tried to make complete string using formatted string and parameters,
and I cannot know the type of the parameters.

So, I need a way to get type from formatted string like "abc %d %f %s".

```
List<SomethingForType> parseTypeFromString(String formattedString) {
    List<SomethingForType> type = new ArrayList<>();
    ...
    // how to determine a type?
    if (string.equals("%d")) type.add(Integer)
    ...

    return type
}

void sample(String str, SomethingForParameter[] parameters) {
    Type[] types = parseTypeFromString(str);
    List<Object> params = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < types.length; i++) {
        switch (types[i]) {
            case Integer:
                params.add(parameters[i].getInt());
                break;
            case String:
                params.add(parameters[i].getString());
                break;
            case Float:
                params.add(parameters[i].getFloat());
                break;
                ....
        }
    }

    String completeString = String.format(str, params.toArray());
}
```

Is there a simple way to do this in Java?

Comment: What is your `Type`? An `Enum`?

Comment: `c == "%d"` - how to compare Strings in Java

Comment: Have you considered using [MessageFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html)?

Comment: `"%s"` can be used on any type. So you can't specify the type.